# about "from sys import argv "

Tags: python

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(b)

print "Here's your file %r:" % b
print txt.read()

print "Type the filename again:"
file_again = raw_input("> ")

txt_again = open(file_again)

print txt_again.read()
```

I run it in `cmd` but it shows that `txt=open(b) 
nameerror:name'b' is not defined..`

I have a  `b.txt`  file. I don't know what's wrong..thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `argv` contains the list of argument passed, `argv[0]` contains the script name and `argv[1]` contains the first argument passed (ie, your filename)

```
script, filename = argv
txt = open(filename)
```